# Why does Makima believe Denji can be the most powerful devil hunter, when Aki was able to defeat the Leech devil and Denji couldn't?

Tags: chainsaw-man

In episode 5 of the Chainsaw Man anime, Makima tells Denji that she believes he can be the best devil hunter. But in a former episode, we saw for example, how Aki was able to defeat the Leech devil, and Denji couldn't.

Why does Makima believe Denji can be the most powerful devil hunter?

Comment: "Can" normally reflects potential, not actual, ability.  Why would she base it on current ability?

Comment: Because if the abilities she sees on him are like any other devil hunter abilities, there is no reason to think that way or she could think like that about any devil hunter. Unless she knows something about him that makes him special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

> Makima knows what Denji is truly capable of, or rather the "chainsaw devil". This devil has the power to erase the existence of anything it eats (canonically Pochita had eaten the Nazis and erased WW2 from history).

This is a reason Makima has high hopes for Denji, but ultimately, she tries to turn him into her pet so she can control him.

Comment: Would you be able to cite sources for where the bit in the spoiler markup is referenced?